# "Please enter a value for amount." when creating invoice with discount with custom price level outside the US

Tags: netsuite

I'm attempting to create invoices via the SOAP web services. The `add` action is failing with the following message:

> ERROR|USER_ERROR|Please enter a value for amount.

There is no `amount` property on the [body of the invoice](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_2/schema/record/invoice.html), just its [line items](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_2/schema/other/invoiceitem.html?mode=package). I checked every line item for the presence of an `amount` property, and they all had one. Eventually, I isolated the issue to the discount line items, as invoices without them were successfully being created. The discount line items are of the form:

```xml
<ns9:item xsi:type="ns9:InvoiceItem">
    <ns9:item xsi:type="ns1670:RecordRef" internalId="80608" xmlns:ns1670="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
    <ns9:amount xsi:type="xsd:double">-6.3</ns9:amount>
    <ns9:quantity xsi:type="xsd:double">1.0</ns9:quantity>
    <ns9:price xsi:type="ns1671:RecordRef" internalId="-1" xmlns:ns1671="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
    <ns9:location xsi:type="ns1672:RecordRef" internalId="118" xmlns:ns1672="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
    <ns9:taxCode xsi:type="ns1673:RecordRef" internalId="63807" xmlns:ns1673="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <ns1673:name xsi:type="xsd:string">AVALARA-VAT - (63807)</ns1673:name>
    </ns9:taxCode>
    <ns9:customFieldList xsi:type="ns1674:CustomFieldList" xmlns:ns1674="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <ns1674:customField xsi:type="ns1674:StringCustomFieldRef" scriptId="custcol_sq_referenceid">
            <ns1674:value xsi:type="xsd:string">51962_discount</ns1674:value>
        </ns1674:customField>
    </ns9:customFieldList>
</ns9:item>
```

Some details about the discount line item (not sure if these are relevant):

- The discount line item itself has a rate, but I've been creating invoices with an amount because these invoices stem from data transformed as part of an integration, and I only have access to the external system's discount amount.
- The discount line item has the Non-Taxable tax schedule, with explicitly defined sales and purchase tax codes for the UK of `UNDEF-GB`.
- The discount line item is assigned an account which includes all subsidiaries.

2 things I've found are:

1. This exact same discount line item has been in other successfully synced invoices, the only difference I've found being that the customer, location, and subsidiary associated with this invoice is in Great Britain, not the US.
2. I'm can create this invoice by not specifying the price level as `-1`, and so have it be undefined.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does NetSuite not think I'm providing a value for the amount of this discount line item only on invoices created in the UK (or not in the US)?
2. Is it good practice to have discount line items have the custom price level (`-1`) or an undefined price level (or does it matter)?

Thanks for taking the time to think about this problem and let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: What I can suggest you is to try doing all the things in the same order using UI which now you are doing through SOAP Services. There maybe an issue with the order in which you are setting the data so just give it a try.

Comment: I agree with @Finnick, the order in which you make selections matters sometimes, this will be evident while working in the UI.  Also while in the UI, take note of all required fields (main and line) and make sure they are all set in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I attempted to create an invoice in the UI identical to what I'm creating via the API, and I encountered the same error _after_ pressing `Save`. I also attempted to create an invoice in the UK in a separate NetSuite sandbox and did not run into this issue. These behaviors makes me think that there may be a script that may be performing some action on `Save` that's actually triggering the error. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a bit of a red herring. While it's not clear what's causing it, price levels are intended to be used with items that are *sold*. Discount items are not sold items, and so it doesn't make NetSuite since to assign them a price level.

Removing the price level from discount line items so it is `undefined` is valid and prevents the error from being thrown.